how to follow up on responses from individuals?
I am a newbie here.  I asked a question a while back and got some immediate responses that lead me to more questions.  Now I am stuck with my problem unsolved.  Is it possible to message some of the individuals who responded to my post, but by direct message?

Any way to send a personal message to another user? was asked 15 years ago for a direct feature request, but that is "status-declined". See also How do I contact other users?
